# Fancybox height issue

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, fancybox

I am using fancybox for loading a Huge form "1300px" height ( i know it is not something good but the client wants it like this) the problem that it doesn`t cover the whole height i tried

autoDimensions

```
$.fancybox.resize
```

with no luck although other parts that uses fancybox is working without a problem so any tips will be great.

also i want to know how to load data (a div) from another HTML inside fancybox?

Answer (score 2):

You should use `{'autoDimensions' : false}`

```
For loading data into fancybox use
$.fancybox({'width': 200, 
            'height': 200, 
            'autoDimensions' : false, 
            'content': $('div.class').html() 
});
```

Hope this is helpful.